# Why can't I set the camera rotation?

Tags: three.js

I've been struggling with an application where I'm trying to set the camera rotation initially so when the scene is loaded, you'll be looking where we want you to look.

The backstory, I'm creating a panorama viewer where the panorama is applied to a mesh with a sphere geometry.

The problem I'm having is I don't seem to be able to set the camera rotation. I've tried multiple attempts, but none have been working. I attempted setting the camera rotation after creating the camera, and I tried applying the target of my orbitcontrols and setting the object rotation in the orbit controls. I haven't had any luck yet with just setting an initial camera rotation.

I'm really hoping at this point that this is due to something minor that I'm over looking.

Here's a source: http://www.freeptools.com/mapster/testing-360s2.php

It shows the camera itself AND the orbit controls object. It also shows what their target is I'm setting, and what they really are. So far I haven't been able to get this to accept anything I give it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THREE.js OrbitControls take over the camera completely, so you should not use that in conjunction with updating camera rotations.

Instead, OrbitControls has methods that help you do this: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js

```
orbitControls.rotateLeft( angle );
orbitControls.rotateUp( angle );
```

In addition, you can move orbitControls.target around (it's a THREE.Vector3) and the camera will just look to that direction.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is the case, but it when I pull the up and left values in one instance than test in another, the positions do not line up. They are however close. For the left value, I have to multiply it by -1. The up value I have to multiply it by .195 and that gets me pretty close. No idea why these aren't lining up right now, but this has gotten me where I need to be so thanks for the help. I've seriously been stuck on this issue for multiple days. I didn't know what an Azimuth or Polar angel were, so I wouldn't have gotten further without you pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: rotateLeft and rotateUp are internal methods